# Ground and neutral 220

Tags: electrical

OK I added an image of the box I am talking about. This is when I first pulled the cover off. Its clean now. Remember this is a modular home that was wired back in the 70's. I moved into it and am trying to figure things out. The two black wires you see are my hots coming in from Panel 1. the black wire with the white tape on it I am assuming is a ground because it has no power and connects to a single lug. The green wire on the bottom also has no power but is connected to the black wire with the white tape down in the pipe somehow. If you look at the top there is an insulated neutral bar with a white wire attached to it. The white wire goes down into the pipe no idea where. The only breaker in this box is the main breaker that shuts off all the power to my house.

[image]I am installing an electric oven in my older modular home. I have 3 power boxes. The first is the primary where the originating power comes in and is attached to a pole. This leads to a secondary box that contains another breaker that shuts off power to the house but not the originating box. A 3rd box runs from this and is attached to my house that has all of the power breakers for the house.
My question is I am going to run a 220 from the second box as it is the only one that has room. This box has only a neutral bar that is grounded to a ground rod in the ground. Can I place both the ground and the neutral wire on this bar (dif screw points) or do I have to install another ground bar and ground rod to run my new 220?

Comment: A bit confusing. Can you upload pictures of boxes 2 & 3? (Even though you think # 3 has no space, it may be possible to do something there.)

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of boxes 2 and 3 please, as well as the labeling on the insides of their covers/doors?

Comment: I presume that is box 2 in the photo you posted? Also, can you post photos of the labeling on its inside please?

Comment: There is no labeling at all. Yes this is box 2. None of my breakers are labeled

Comment: There is labeling on the left and right side panels and on the flipped up front panel. The one of the right has a colored bar at the top of the label (towards the back of the box) - I suspect that label is a generic "Danger!" label and not device-specific details.

Comment: For future reference, you can simply upload the picture itself instead of a screen shot of the picture in a photo editor.